# semi-transparent images for all browsers?

Tags: image, internet-explorer

I need to use many semi-transparent images for my website.

I was wondering what's the most convenient format, considering I want the semi-transparency perfectly working on internet explorer 6-7-8 as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one format you can use, which is PNG24, as far as I know. IE7 and 8 do display them the right way most of the time (unless you fading them in or out). For IE6, you'll have to use some kind of png fix... Google for it, you'll come up with a ton of them.

by png 24 I mean png 24bit

Comment: Yes. If I were first to answer, I'd have said exactly that.